# How to print intermediate values for debugging from inside a constant function?

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, syntax-error

Let's say I have the [following code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9b68175a69d925e68aa3f68396e4acc9)

```
const fn test() -> i64 {
    println!("Hello");
    34
}
```

Which produces the following error:

```
error[E0015]: calls in constant functions are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
```

What is the correct syntax to do this?

Comment: This sounds like the [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why are you trying to print something out from a constant function? They are, by definition, constant, and unable to print out values.

Comment: @Aplet123 indeed I want to do something like this https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2dbc55cc199adf4652743a981997a4c7. and I would like to debug something while the constant function is called.

Comment: Then make it non-const, debug it, then make it const again. (or use an actual debugger)

Comment: @Aplet123 hence this compiler error in such case `error[E0015]: calls in statics are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants`.

Comment: It looks like the real question is "how do I _debug intermediate values_ inside a const function". I've updated it to better communicate that.

Answer (score 3):

If a function prints then it cannot be a `const` function.

Part of the point of `const` functions is that the compiler can do optimisations like evaluating them at compile-time. Printing just doesn't make sense.

Comment: But my exact problem is this one https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2dbc55cc199adf4652743a981997a4c7. I need the public variable to be accessible from several threads.

Comment: @user2284570 That's a different question to what you asked. But it sounds like you want a `static` var, probably initialized with `lazy_static`.

Comment: No need for the syscall overhead of a mutex (which is about 20µs on my machine), since the variable is accessed only for reading but not for writing.

Comment: @user2284570 `lazy_static` does not require that you use a `mutex`.

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed but the type returned by `std::mem::transmute()` isn t a ref right?

Comment: Because this is what I m trying to assign to the static variable.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to `panic!` instead:

```
#![feature(const_panic)]

const fn test() -> i64 {
    panic!("Hello");
    34
}
```

This requires a Nightly compiler, and causes compilation to fail. But if you're just debugging then these caveats should be okay.

Comment: The problem is the first time it s ok. This is for the second time, I want to see what happens.

Comment: And using panic! stops the program.

Comment: @user2284570 You can use `panic!()` inside an `if` that matches the conditions of your second invocation, the one that presumably produces an incorrect result. And, obviously, include the values you want displayed, in the `panic`. Doesn't that solve your issue?